# Arquillian and JBoss Wildfly

Tags: jboss, jboss-arquillian, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am currently trying to run arquillian tests with jboss wildfly but a java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy exception is thrown while running it.

I have follwing configuration: 
jboss wildfly-8.1.0.CR1
derby 10.9.1.0

For using derby networkServer (not inmemory) I have deployed derbyclient.jar in jboss Wildfly (Name=derbyclient.jar, Runtime Name: derbyclient.jar)

maven project structure:

```
example
    example-ear
    example-ejb
    example-web
```

The Arquillian testcase is contained in example-ejb project.

pom (arquillian-container is wildfly-arquillian-container-managed-8.0.0.Final) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Arquillian JUnit Testcase:

```
...
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class PersonIT {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addPackage("example.util")
                .addPackage("example.model")
                .addPackage("example.model.constraints")
                .addPackage("example.model.embeddables")
                .addPackage("example.model.enumeration")
                .addPackage("example.model.listeners")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/default_mapping.xml", "META-INF/default_mapping.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                // Deploy our test datasource
                .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml", "test-ds.xml")
                ;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction utx;


    @Before
    public void preparePersistenceTest() throws Exception {
        clearData();
        insertData();
        startTransaction();
    }
    ...

    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.commit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

test-persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/npptDS</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/default_mapping.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="chapter04Create.ddl"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="chapter04Drop.ddl"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="import.sql"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

test-ds.xml (contained in ejb maven project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/npptDS"
                pool-name="npptDS"
                enabled="true"
                use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/nppt</connection-url>
        <driver>derbyclient.jar</driver>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Exception while running arquillian test:

```
07:26:45,536 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
07:26:45,545 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) HHH000328: Unable to load/access derby driver class sysinfo to check versions : org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @43a2a89a (finder: local module finder @6beb3926 (roots: D:\05_programme\jboss\wildfly-8.1.0.CR1\modules,D:\05_programme\jboss\wildfly-8.1.0.CR1\modules\system\layers\base))]
07:26:45,604 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#primary": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."test.war#primary": java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3178) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3137) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:131) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:84) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:221) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3178) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3158) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.getPhysicalAnnotations(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:2975) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.initAnnotations(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:345) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.isAnnotationPresent(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaXAnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(JavaXAnnotatedElement.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.syncAnnotatedClasses(Configuration.java:3723) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1409) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397) [hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.CR1.jar:8.1.0.CR1]
    ... 8 more

07:26:45,617 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"test.war#primary\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"test.war#primary\": java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy"}}
07:26:45,619 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"test.war#primary\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"test.war#primary\": java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy"}}
07:26:45,626 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment test.war
07:26:45,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'test.war#primary'
07:26:45,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/npptDS]
07:26:45,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test.war (runtime-name: test.war) in 78ms
07:26:45,702 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Max

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it.
The problem was that one package was missing in micro deployment.

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addPackage("example.util")
            .addPackage("example.model")
            .addPackage("example.model.constraints")
            .addPackage("example.model.embeddables")
            .addPackage("example.model.enumeration")
            .addPackage("example.model.listeners")
            .addPackage("example.model.validator")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsResource("META-INF/default_mapping.xml", "META-INF/default_mapping.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            // Deploy our test datasource
            .addAsWebInfResource("test-ds.xml", "test-ds.xml")
            ;
}
```

The exception message is not good.
There is context missing in the message. 
So maybe hibernate should log the class which is currently processed or something else.

org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader

```
private void initAnnotations() {
    if ( annotations == null ) {
        XMLContext.Default defaults = xmlContext.getDefault( className );
        if ( className != null && propertyName == null ) {
            //is a class
            Element tree = xmlContext.getXMLTree( className );
            Annotation[] annotations = getPhysicalAnnotations();
            ...
}
```

Comment: You probably would want to use `.addPackages(true, "example")` to avoid such problems.